# What is the area of shaded region in the figure shown?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Is there any geometric solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: I suspect not. Where does the problem come from? Why are you supposed to assume $\pi = 3$?!

Comment: What does $\pi=3$ mean?

Comment: @CameronBuie I don't know. I think is rounded to 3

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Anand I tried to solve it as in this video, but the solution seems to be difficult.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Seb863FnfU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: What do you mean by “geometric solution”? Geometrically constructing the figure should be easy, Computing the area is not something I'd consider a geometric approach, more algebraic. The resulting area will *very* likely be transcendental, and chances are it will be a transcendental multiple of $\pi$ as well. Have you worked out the edge length of the square? How would you decompose the figure into easier shapes, and which of these is giving you trouble?

Comment: @MvG I need a solution. Possibly an elegant solution as simple as possible. Thank you.

Comment: I won't work on any problem that asks me to assume $\pi = 3$.

Answer (score 2):

From $\triangle BCD$, (1) get $BC = 4 \sqrt 3$ and (2) get $[\triangle BCD] = ([2] + [3]) = 8 \sqrt 3$.

[image]

Let arc AC cut BD at X. From $\triangle ODX$, get [1] using sine law and area formula.

[2] = [sector OCX] – [1].

[3] = ([2] + [3]) – [2].

Find [s] by simple subtraction.